# Music player for Android, files-and-directories based and with a lockscreen window

Tags: android, music, media-player

Desired features:

- Playing Android-supported media files;
- Ability to be shown atop of Android lock screen, with:

  - Seeking bar;
  - Buttons for switching to next/prev file;
  - Buttons for switching to next/prev directory;
  - **Buttons for switching to 10'th next/prev directory**

    It should work like the previous button pressed 10 (or N) times;
- Usual music player features like pausing on headphones disconnection or a phone call.
- Maybe accepting commands (like "switch to next directory") from command line or some socket (i.e. from HTTP), or as some `adb shell am start ....` things. Or there should be API for plugins. Or the player should be open source to implement something like that myself.

Album art is not needed, metadata like ID3 is not needed.

I should specify the directory, like `/sdcard/music`, and it should scan and be able to navigate directories and files from it from the lock screen fast. New or removed files should not cause trouble.

Open source is preferred, as usual.

Comment: Not using it myself, but check my list for [FolderPlay & AudioBooks](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_folderplay). Take a special look at [MortPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer) – AFAIR that's coming closest to your requirements.

Comment: I actually use MortPlayer currently. But it's too tedious to press "prev directory" button on the lockscreen 30 times to reach the music. And I'm not sure there is API to press this button programatically.

Comment: I found some indicators Mortplayer could be controled with [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) (e.g. in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1118891&page=223&highlight=Mortplayer), I've highlighted "Mortplayer" for you), but I didn't try that myself. According to [Izzy's collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker), [GoneMad](http://www.appbrain.com/app/gonemad.gmmp) comes with direct *Tasker* support – and it also supports "Folder Play".

Comment: Also MorePlayer is bad at missing/new files in the directory. It requires rescan that cannot be performed from lock screen, the rescan can be slow (there are a lot of little MIDIs).

Comment: @Vi. My suggestion is [poweramp](http://powerampapp.com/), [poweramp on googleplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en)